# Cucumber JVM Junit Issue

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I'm trying to run the test, but I'm getting this error trace of:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface cucumber.api.java.Before doesn't have @Indexed
at org.jvnet.hudson.annotation_indexer.Index.list(Index.java:45)
at org.jvnet.hudson.annotation_indexer.Index.list(Index.java:28)
at cucumber.runtime.java.BetterJavaBackend.loadGlue(BetterJavaBackend.java:82)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:88)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:66)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:62)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.createRuntime(Cucumber.java:74)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:61)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Does anybody know what that means? I'm getting befuddled here. Mainly the part about the
    interface cucumber.api.java.Before doesn't have @Indexed

BTW, I'm not using maven, I'm importing jars into the libraries.

Comment: what version of cucumber-jvm you have? what other libraries do you have in your classpath?

Comment: I have 1.1.6 version for all the .jar files. Cucumber-annotation-indexer, cucumber-core, cucumber-html, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit, cucumber-jvm-deps, gherkin-2.12, gherkin-jvm-deps-1.02

Comment: Without any code to reference, this is going to be a bit tough. I would suggest first looking over the readme file for cucumber annotation indexer on github. The last line reads "Put this jar in your dependency instead of cucumber-java, and Cucumber should find this backend automatically."